# SPARQL Query Computational Complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, rdf, time-complexity, sparql

I have a list of SPARQL queries with various patterns (e.g., select, union, join). I want to calculate their time complexity by using big O notation (e.g., O(n), O(nlogn)). Please let me know how to do that. I have more than 3000,0000,000 triples in my RDF graph.

Followings are some example query queries

```
Query 1:
select ?o  where { <http://example.com/person_info/242622027> vocab:info_gender ?o}

Query 2:
select ?o ?k where {
  {
    ?s vocab:person_info_pid  '242622027'^^xsd:decimal. 
    ?s vocab:person_info_homeloc ?o
  }
 UNION
  {
   ?i vocab:activities_pid '242622027'^^xsd:decimal. 
   ?i vocab:activities_purpose ?k                 
  }
 }

Query3: 
select (count(*) as ?no) where{
  ?s vocab:outputparttwo_iteration '0'^^xsd:decimal
  }
```

Comment: You have more than 30 billion triples in a graph?

Comment: SPARQL is just a query language;  implementations can implement things in lots of different ways, so there's no general answer for the runtime complexity of a given query.  It depends on the implementation.  That said, large triple stores will typically index data, so query 1 and query 3 will be pretty quick.  Query two is probably O(O(?s ?o query) + O(?i ?k query)).

Comment: Yes I have a large graph. I can understand about SPARQL implementation. Suppose there is no indexing then what will be the complexity for Query 1 and 3? For Query 2 you said complexity may be O(O(?s ?o query) + O(?i ?k query). What is "query" here? Is there any cost for joining?

Comment: By "?s ?o query" and "?i ?k query" I meant the two sides of the union query, because to evaluate a query, you're essentially (unless some optimization happens) doing each of the two queries separately and concatenating the results, so to evaluate both would take the sum of the times to evaluate each of them.  There's no real "joining", just concatenation.

Comment: Without knowing about the implementation, it's hard to say anything about runtime, really.  E.g., to answer query 1 you'd pretty much have to iterate through each of the triples in the graph and check, so O(n).  Same thing for query 3 O(n). For query two you'd end up having to do something similar, but it'd probably be O(2 n^2) = O(n^2).  But it really doesn't make sense to ask if you don't know the implementation of the system.

Answer (score 4):

SPARQL itself is [PSPACE-complete](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~cgutierr/papers/sparql.pdf).  You can probably only come up with the best case complexity for any given query.  The real-world complexity will depend on the implementation of the database to some degree.